# Приложение не устанавливается на ios 8.1.3

Tags: xcode, ios

Написал приложение в xcode 6, всем доволен, протестировал на 4s, все работает, пришёл друг с 5s, и на него приложение не ставится, у него стоит прошивка 8.1.3, а в моём xcode максимальная прошивка 8,0 (как я понял), неужели ничего нельзя сделать кроме как скачивать новый xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать ipa через архивирование проекта (Product/Archive) и экспорт этого архива (Window/Organizer , вкладка Archive, далее выбираем тот архив что нужен и Export -> Save for AdHock). Далее эту ипашку можно поставить на любой из девайсов прописанных в провижине вашего приложения, версия оси может быть любая (разумеется, выше DEployment target т.е. ipa имеет ограничение только снизу, хотя это и не гарантирует от каких-то отличий апи). Проверено неоднократно в том числе на девайсах к которым не было физического доступа

А сам xcode да, ограничен жестко и с двух сторон - может запускать только под конкретные версии, возможно это как-то и решается (скорее всего установкой сдк новой версии), но сам не пробовал

Comment: @aknew значит только установка нового xcode? А приложение нужно будет с нуля переписывать или можно будет просто в новом открыть?

Comment: просто открыть. Временное решение с ипа я вам подсказал, для тестов этого обычно хватает